# Is it possible to import DBs information_schema, performance_schema and mysql from mysql-community-server-5.6.x to mariadb-server-5.5.x?

Tags: mariadb, mysqld

Is it possible to import the following DBs from an existing mysql-community-server-5.6.x configuration to a fresh mariadb-server-5.5.x :

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

I guess no here because the table structure of mysql.users should be different between mysqld and mariadb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe* some of it.

`information_schema` is not a real set of tables; it is in-memory data that pretends to be tables.  So, a definite "no" for that.

`performance_schema` is mostly transient, so don't bother.

`mysql` changes between versions, so it would be risky to do so.  Use `mysqldump` (or other tool) to dump routines.  Do `SHOW GRANTS ...` to get grant statements to replay; this is somewhat tedious.  Start fresh for most things in `mysql`.

Also, Oracle 5.6 to MariaDB 5.5 is a step backward in many aspects.  Can't you go to 10.0, at least?  That version has more of what is in 5.6.